# Canvas Array for holding multiple Draw Image's

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

I'm currently developing a space invaders themed canvas game and I have run into the problem of needing to draw the same picture (The aliens for instance) multiple times. Now From my basic knowledge of JavaScript and toying with my current build I'm assuming that I would need to have an array to be able to have multiple instance's of pictures through the drawimage method to be able to have many pictures rather than one constantly moving. My thinking is that also by doing it through an array I will also be able to assign an ID to the images that are being drawn so that later collision programming will be possible.

My question for you is what is the correct way to build such and array to be able to through out about ten pictures all in a line with about 20px difference in there X angle and also assign them an ID.

I have found little in terms of guidance into doing such a thing through Google searches so any examples or material your able to link me to would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

**EDIT**

```
<!-- language: javascript -->
var environment = function (opt) {
var self = this, shapes = [], shapeImage;
var options = opt || {}, canvasId = options.canvasId || {}, rowNum = options.rowNum || 5, colNum = options.colNum || 5, shapeImageUrl = options.imageURL || '';
var loopInterval, context;

var update = function () {
for (var x = 0; x < shapes.lenght; x++) {
    if (shapes[x].x + 1 < colNum) {
     shapes[x].x++;

     if (shapes[x].x == rowNum - 1) {
      shapes[x].y++;
     }
   }
  }
};

var draw = function () {
 for(var x = 0; x < shapes.length; x++){
  if(shapes[x].X == 0 && shapes[x].Y > 0)
    context.clearRect((colNum - 1) * shapes[x].Width ,(shapes[x].Y -1) *     shapes[x].Height, shapes[x].Width, shapes[x].Height);   

  else
    context.clearRect((shapes[x].X - 1) * shapes[x].Width, (shapes[x].Y) * shapes[x].Height, shapes[x].Width, shapes[x].Height);

  context.drawImage(shapeImage, shapes[x].X * shapes[x].Width, shapes[x].Y * shapes[x].Height);

  }
};
 var initCanvas = function() {
 if (canvasId) {
   var canvas = getElementById(canvasId);
   context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  }
 };

 var initShapes = function (rows, cols) {
  var num = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
     shapes.push(new shape(num, i, j));

   }
  }
};
var tick = function () {
 update();
 draw();
};

return function () {
  self.shape = function () {

   return function (id, x, y) {
    this.X = x;
    this.Y = y;
    this.Id = id;
   };
   };
  this.shape.prototype.Width = 30;
  this.shape.prototype.Height = 30;

  this.start = function () {
   initCanvas();
   initShapes(rowNum, colNum);

   shapeImage = new Image();
   shapeImage.url = shapeImageUrl;
   shapeImage.onload = function() {
    loopInterval = setInterval(tick(), 1000 / 60);

    };
  };
 };
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not looking to get around this by using a framework Just because I'd prefer to understand how it would be manually done in base Javascript :)